# How to load images in a folder inside view folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

Pls my fellow CI programmers, i have a project, my admin folder and my gallery folder is inside view folder, how can i load the images in the gallery folder in my admin?

This is my line of code

```
<?php if(!empty($myusers)): foreach($myusers as $post): ?>
   <?php
      $file1 = $post['file1'];
   ?>

<img src="<?php echo base_url()."gallery_pics/$file1"; ?>" class="img-
responsive" >

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My problem is that the images do not display, the file name is loaded properly but with a wrong path, thanks in advance

Comment: base_url is wrong?

Comment: Use this `<img src="<?php echo base_url('gallery_pics/$file1'); ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no files are directly accessible from view folder. That's why we use the controllers. So it is suggested to keep the resource files(js, images, CSS etc) outside of the application folder to access in your view.

```
  admin
    |__ application
    |__system
    |__assets(JS, images, css files)
       |__gallery_pics
    |__index.php
```

Now your code should be changed as follows

```
<?php if(!empty($myusers)): foreach($myusers as $post): ?>
   <?php
      $file1 = $post['file1'];
   ?>

<img src="<?php echo base_url()."assets/gallery_pics/$file1"; ?>" class="img-responsive" >

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I hope this would help you.